# insert character after first character in string?

Tags: php

```
$var = "Hello";
```

How can I insert the character **:** in after the first character of the string above ? The first character could be anything. So I want to do something like

```
$res = add("Hello");
echo $res; // which return H:ello
```

I know how to do this through `str_replace` but this needs the first character to be always the same..

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use string append and substr to do it

```
  $var = $var[0].":".substr($var,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = substr($str, 0, 1) . ':' . substr($str, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newstr = substr_replace($oldstr, $str_to_insert, $pos, 0);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: What should I have to type in $oldstr, does it accept an index ? please note that I don't know what is the first charachter. it's not always the same @0x4139

Comment: @ShikataGaNai `substr_replace('Hello', ':', 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I would probably try this:

```
$string = "Hello";
$new_string = substr($string,0,1) . ":" . substr($string,1, strlen($string)-1);
```

This would get H (= first char) + : (= fixed char) + ello (= the rest of the string)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    function addColon($myString){
     return $myString = substr($myString, 0, 1) . ':' . substr($myString, 1);
    }

    echo addColon("Hello");
?>
```